# Command prompt indicates a changed computer name; possibly hacked?

Tags: command-line, virus

I've noticed that lately my Macbook Pro often becomes unresponsive and slow. I recently also noticed that the prompt of my Fish shell has changed to indicate that the computer name is `SurfaceDePapi`:

[image]

I don't recall changing anything here. As far as I know, the name of my computer has always been "Kurt's Macbook Pro":

[image]

and before, the command prompt ended with `Kurts-Macbook-Pro`.

Could this be an indication that my Mac has been hacked?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Host file. https://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want

If the host is set to surfacedepepi then there could be some DNS information in the host file.

It would certainly be a sloppy man in the middle attack if they compromised the host file and then put what could be surface of Pepi in half a dozen languages into the host.

Also, when did this start happening? You can look at your logs around this time.
https://www.howtogeek.com/356942/how-to-view-the-system-log-on-a-mac/
Anyone who was sloppy enough to change the hostname might be careless enough to leave the logs.